# React Native - What is the difference between setState & setNativeProps?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6, jsx

I want to prevent re-rendering of the whole tree, so, I thought to use the `setNativeProps` to update the specific component when needed, but `setNativeProps` is not working for all components. I am using both `setState` and `setNativeProps` in my react native application. The `setState` works just fine for all components but `setNativeProps` do not works for all components.

What is the difference between `setState` & `setNativeProps`? For what kind of components `setNativeProps` should and shouldn't be used? A little example will be more appreciated. Thanks !!!

Comment: have you seen [article in react native blog](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/direct-manipulation) on setNativeProps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The React-Native Documentation explains this very well :

> It is sometimes necessary to make changes directly to a component without using state/props to trigger a re-render of the entire subtree. When using React in the browser for example, you sometimes need to directly modify a DOM node, and the same is true for views in mobile apps. setNativeProps is the React Native equivalent to setting properties directly on a DOM node.

check [this link](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/direct-manipulation)  for reference

> Use setNativeProps when frequent re-rendering creates a performance bottleneck

so basically the only use case i can see for it, is when you are creating continuous animations and you don't want to affect the performance of your app.
in almost all other cases, setState will be more than enough.
And in case you need to control when your component should re-render check out 
[shouldComponentUpdate](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate)

Comment: **shouldComponentUpdate** link says **Page Not Found**.